# How can account abstraction replace EOA?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, metamask

I have been exploring account abstraction for a while now. But still some questions are unanswered to me.

My questions are as follow -

1. If only a particular nft owner can claim free erc20 token, will account abstraction work? As under the hood the bundle is the one that initiates all transactions and not the owner of the nft?
2. It is claimed almost everywhere, that we can incorporate our own logic in the wallet contract. But not sure what kind of logic and how?
3. Is paymaster is some kind of  contract that is provided by stack up or any other service provider, or I could be a paymaster myself for my end users too?
4. What if as a paymaster, I want to be payed with my own erc20 token, is it possible? If yes do I need to deploy a custom paymaster contract? If not what are the available erc20 tokens?
5. If I want to import the private key in metamask will it work as an eoa?
6. Is there any tutorial that demonstrates the whole front end integration with the smart wallet?
7. Has this standard been approved to be used in production yet?

Answer (score 1):

1. *If only a particular nft owner can claim free erc20 token, will account abstraction work? As under the hood the bundle is the one that initiates all transactions and not the owner of the nft?*

   - Yes, as in that case, the NFT holder will be your ERC4337 Contract Account, and the method calls in the claiming process would look like this: `EntryPoint` → `ERC4337 Account` → `Claiming Contract`. In the `claim` method we usually check `msg.sender` to hold the NFT (not the `tx.origin`) , and in that flow `msg.sender` is your ERC4337 Account.
2. *It is claimed almost everywhere, that we can incorporate our own logic in the wallet contract. But not sure what kind of logic and how?*

   - `EntryPoint` contract doesn't hold the account's implementation. You provide your `AccountFactory` contract which creates a new `ERC4337 Contract Account` for you. It means `Account` contract developer can add any feature inside the account contract.
3. *Is paymaster is some kind of contract that is provided by stack up or any other service provider, or I could be a paymaster myself for my end users too?*

   - It is important to understand, after you have created and signed your `UserOperation` data - **anybody** can send it to the blockchain - with some EOA, your friend, or some 3rd party service. And there are a couple of ways how gas refunds are handled:

     - no gas refund. For example, when you execute the `UserOperation` with your other EOA.
     - gas refunds directly from ERC4337 Account, for example - deposit funds to your account contract address, and the used `ETH` for gas will be sent to the beneficiary address from that account.
     - paymaster contracts - `EntryPoint` can ask another contract to pay for the `UserOperation` gas, but your `UserOperation` should be eligible (depends on implementation) - `Paymaster` validates and transfers the required amount.
4. *What if as a paymaster, I want to be paid with my own erc20 token, is it possible? If yes do I need to deploy a custom paymaster contract? If not what are the available erc20 tokens?*

   - Yes and yes. You deploy the paymaster contract after the `UserOperation` was executed, the `EntryPoint` calls you the paymaster `postOp` method providing the amount of gas consumed, and the `UserOperation` you can collect the required amount of `erc20` tokens from the User and provide the required amount of ETH to the `EntryPoint`. *To note: your paymaster contract should be allowed to transfer the tokens*
5. *If I want to import the private key in metamask will it work as an eoa?*

   - There are no private keys for the `ERC4337 Contract Account`. You would add the `Contract Account` address and additionally would add the private key of the owner. But it depends on the `ERC4337` infrastructure. In the very basic example the `ERC4337` would consist of the normal `EOA` and the `ERC4337 Contract Account`, but some services may create another setup with internal accounts so that you won't need the metamask at all.
     The process will be similar to how the **Rabby Wallet** implements Safe Accounts (multi sigs) - you add the owner account (EOA) and the safe address.
6. *Is there any tutorial that demonstrates the whole front-end integration with the smart wallet?*

   - Not sure about the frontend - here is the basic implementation of the contracts https://github.com/eth-infinitism/account-abstraction after you understand the flows to create the UI for that setup is obvious.
7. *Has this standard been approved to be used in production yet?*

   - Yes, but the [standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-4337.md) is a low-level specification, the actual implementation could be very different.